# How to count input throughout the day averaged by weekdays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get an output of the average amount of tasks solved by hour throughout the day.
But I want to get this average amount by an hour of the day throughout the week.

number of tasks

```
7AM (avg of all 7-8AM on Monday to Friday) 
8AM
9AM
etc
```

```sql
select count(*),
       date_trunc('hour', tasks) as "dateAxis",
FROM tasks
group by "dateAxis"
```

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0Q38JVBD)

`date_trunc('hour', ...)` only "cuts off" the minutes and seconds, so to speak. So you
are normalizing your datetime value to hours. The date will be kept. For example: `2010-01-02 12:23:42` will be converted to `2010-01-02 12:00:00`. So, because the date will be kept, you cannot group throughout different dates but only throughout the related hour. Instead you could use `extract('hour' from ...)` which extracts the `hour` value of your datetime as a separate value which can be used for grouping throughout different days.

The following query groups all given dates be their hour:

```
select count(*),
       extract('hour', tasks) as "dateAxis"
FROM tasks
group by "dateAxis"
```

If you only want to recognize all days of a certain week, you'll need to recognize the `week` number as as well in your group:

```
SELECT
    count(*),
    extract('week' from mydate) as week,
    extract('hour' from mydate) as hour
FROM mytable
GROUP BY week, hour
```

Of course, if you are dealing with data sets which include different years, you should add the `year` component into your group as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

The thing is im trying to get the average tasks count throughout days so what get an number that is the average amount of tasks per hour per the range of dates im choosing

Comment: @sojectcs16 Please add a minimized example and the expected output to your question.

Comment: try to use day of week:  extract(DOW from mydate),extract('hour' from mydate) for group by clause